# Conquest of Camelot - Riddle stone

Tags: conquest-of-camelot

I'm playing again Conquest of Camelot and there is a riddle at the force field barrier at the 5 stones that I don't know the answer. Here it is:

```
Bright as diamond,
Loud as thunder,
Never still,
A thing of wonder.
What am I?
```

If you know the answer, please let me know because that's the only riddle missing to go thru the barrier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is waterfall.  A cheatsheet can be found [here](http://www.sierrahelp.com/Hints/ConquestsOfCamelotRiddles.html).

Comment: WOW! That was fast! I was going to sleep because I couldn't think of an answer. Thank you!